# How do I sort DataList by result of function - SilverStripe 4

Tags: sorting, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I have a set of objects `Person` that I would like to sort based on a score that is calculated by a  function on the object `Score()`.

While I can easily display the `Score()` in ModelAdmin I am unable to sort by that field as it's not a db field. The score changes each day based on a few of the other fields in the db so it's not something that would be suitable to store itself.

I suspected there would be a function which is the equivilent of `filterByCallback()` such as `sortByCallback()` but I can't seem to find that existing.

I don't need it to be added in the ModelAdmin gridField but I would like to use it in a report. How have others got around this problem?

Cheers

Comment: Doing those sorts of computations in memory is really bad practice. How realistic would it be for you to take everything that contributes to the `Score()` computation and ensure that `Person` gets written with a new native `Score` db field every time one of those things changes? Just because it's a computed value doesn't mean it can't be stored as data. Worst case, you hand it off to a cron task or something.

Comment: Yea true, I hadn’t thought about the memory aspect - it would update each day or when values are changed in admin. So yea probably better to run a cron job just after midnight and on any changes. Basically is a waiting list that looks at how many days they’ve been waiting and their priority and assigns a score based on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always sort with the native PHP methods. Eg.

```
$list = Person::get()->toArray();
usort($list, function($a, $b){
    // will sort in descending order. To reverse, swap $b and $a
    return $b->Score() - $a->Score();
});
```

If you need to, you can then still convert to an `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList::create($list);
```

As UncleCheese pointed out in his comment, this can be quite slow and memory intensive… it really depends on how many records you're planning to sort.